# Windows Phone does not set SelectedItem when ItemTemplate has ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm using the [`ReorderListBox` control](http://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/) that allows for items to be drag/dropped around in a listbox.

I'm also using `MvvmLight`, an `EventTrigger` and the `EventToCommand` class to capture the Tap event and execute a `RelayCommand` handler. Everything works fine when I have a plain old `StackPanel` as my item template for my listbox. However, as soon as I stick a `ScrollViewer` in there, my `SelectedItem` comes up as null. Is there a way to get the item that should be bound to that scroll viewer? Code below.

**ViewModel**

```
public ViewModelClass
{
    ...

    public ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> MyItemsSource { get; private set; }

    public RelayCommand<MyItemViewModel> EditItemCommand { get; private set; }

    public ViewModelClass()
    {
        EditItemCommand = new RelayCommand<MyItemViewModel>(OnEditItem);
    }

    private void OnEditItem(MyItemViewModel parameter)
    {
        // parameter is always null, even when I change the type of the RelayCommand to object
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<rlb:ReorderListBox x:Name="MyListBox" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" IsReorderEnabled="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,4" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Border Background="DarkGoldenrod" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Margin="6,3" Text="{Binding AnotherProperty}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" />
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
</rlb:ReorderListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<rlb:ReorderListBox x:Name="MyListBox" SelectionMode="Single" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" 
                           IsReorderEnabled="True"
                           Height="400">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<rlb:ReorderListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,4" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</rlb:ReorderListBox.Template>
<rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Border Background="DarkGoldenrod" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Margin="6,3" Text="{Binding AnotherProperty}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Height is important here since you need to specify it to make **ScrollViewer** working.

However that makes selecting working kinda bad? Like multiple items get selected... I don't know if it's bug with control itself or what.

I would try to use **SelectionChanged** event instead of **Tap** and get item which is selected for real there, then process it.

Comment: Can't use SelectionChanged because that doesn't fire if you hit the same item as you did last time (or if there is only one item). I was using it before.